# How can I change the title of the cancel button of a search bar?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uisearchbar, searchbar

I am trying to learn SwiftUI. I am making a Contacts app and I want to customize `.searchable()` filter's "cancel" button text. I want to change that text and want to write different thing. How can I do that. If I want to do same thing in the Swift5 this was very easy thing to do but when it comes to SwiftUI, things can be different.

I want to change title of "cancel" button.

[image: 1]

```
.searchable(text: $searchableText, prompt: "Look for a contact")
        .onChange(of: searchableText) { searchableText in
            contactVM.filteredContact = contactVM.contact.filter({ contact in
                contact.ad.lowercased().contains(searchableText.lowercased())
            })
        }
```

How can I customize that?

Comment: I don't think you can do it just yet. Probably your best bet is to create a custom search bar: https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-search-bar/

Comment: thanks for helping, I guess it's a template apple gives us and it is not changable.